# Android Overscroll Color change in styles

Tags: android, android-listview, android-styles, overscroll, android-overscoll

Is there a way to change my overscroll color (for a ListView) in my styles.xml?  I really want it to apply to the whole theme of my app.

Comment: I also want to know it. Do you find a solution?

Comment: @mars3142 You should look into the styling in the newest AppCompat.  It will actually handle the colorings for you now.